# Strunk & White/Copy Editor Calculation Bug

Tags: support, badges, edit-badges

I have over 216 edits on Stack Overflow. I understand the edits to my own questions and answers do not count, however my count should be way above the 67 or so that I have credit for.

I've read most of the posts on here on the subject, and I think I figured it out. If you edit the body or title; and, the tag(s) then the edit does not count toward the [Copy Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188732) badge.

I get that just modifying a question's tags should not be counted toward the Copy Editor badge, but I think it is a bit of a bug if you do both and it does not count.

What say ye?

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion? Tag-only edits do not count, you have to edit the body or title in order for an edit to count. Just browsing through your activity, I see a *lot* of retag-only edits just on your first page - so that count doesn't really surprise me.

Comment: Please read the post.  I _think_ I figured it out.  I have edited the body of many more posts then the 67 I have credit for.  Given my super ninja development skills, I am most likely correct.

Comment: I think you're just overestimating how many post bodies you have actually edited... Going by just the edit reasons in your activity alone, 67 is pretty close to the number of badge-eligible edits you've made. Keep in mind that edits to posts which get deleted stop counting towards your total, and multiple edits to the same post only count once.

Comment: @animuson how would you know that?  I've edited well over 150 bodies of posts.

Comment: @Pete Go to your [activity tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1958461/pete-belford?tab=activity). It lists all of the edits you've made. I know you're *suggesting* edits, so you also have to realize that suggestions that get rejected do not count towards the count either. I see you've had 56 rejected, although I wouldn't know how many of those were tag-only.

Comment: Ninja or not, editing both the body and the tags definitely counts toward badge progress. Also, your comments about "Engrish" are displayed to the original posters of questions you edit, and would probably be offensive, if you actually used the term correctly.

Comment: *[unable to fetch current value of cell being edited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910983)* should have been rejected by the reviewers as too minor - a lot more could be done.